# Get entity's children in cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

When i'm loading a kml file in the cesium viewer I get KmlDataSource contains the entities that are in the kml. The problem is that the hierarchy of the kml is not available.

in every entity there is property named "_children", but it exists only in the Unminified, so we can't use it. currently we are creating the hierarchy using the "parent" property but its pretty ugly.

thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Can you share a plnkr/codepen demonstrating your issue.